# What are all the Unicode properties a Perl 6 character will match?

Tags: unicode, raku

The `.uniprop` returns a single property:

```
put join ', ', 'A'.uniprop;
```

I get back one property (the general category):

```
Lu
```

Looking around I didn't see a way to get all the other properties (including derived ones such as `ID_Start` and so on). What am I missing? I know I can go look at the data files, but I'd rather have a single method that returns a list.

I am mostly interested in this because regexes understand properties and match the right properties. I'd like to take any character and show which properties it will match.

Comment: `'A'.uniprop('GeneralCategory')`

Answer (score 2):

`"A".uniprop("Alphabetic")` will get the Alphabetic property. Are you asking for what other properties are possible?

All these that have a checkmark by them will likely work. This just displays that status of roast testing for it https://github.com/perl6/roast/issues/195

This may more more useful for you, https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/core/Cool.pm6#L396-L483
The first hash is just mapping aliases for the property names to the full names. The second hash specifices whether the property is B for boolean, S for a string, I for integer, nv for numeric value, na for Unicode Name and a few other specials.

If I didn't understand you question please let me know and I will revise this answer.

Update: Seems you want to find out all the properties that will match. What you will want to do is iterate all of https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/core/Cool.pm6#L396-L483 and looking only at string, integer and boolean properties. Here is the full thing: https://gist.github.com/samcv/ae09060a781bb4c36ae6cac80ea9325f

```
sub MAIN {
    use Test;
    my $char = 'a';
    my @result = what-matches($char);
    for @result {
        ok EVAL("'$char' ~~ /$_/"), "$char ~~ /$_/";
    }
}
use nqp;
sub what-matches (Str:D $chr) {
    my @result;
    my %prefs = prefs();
    for %prefs.keys -> $key {
        given %prefs{$key} {
            when 'S' {
                my $propval = $chr.uniprop($key);
                if $key eq 'Block' {
                    @result.push: "<:In" ~ $propval.trans(' ' => '') ~ ">";
                }
                elsif $propval {
                    @result.push: "<:" ~ $key ~ "<" ~ $chr.uniprop($key) ~ ">>";
                }
            }
            when 'I' {
                @result.push: "<:" ~ $key ~ "<" ~ $chr.uniprop($key) ~ ">>";
            }
            when 'B' {
                @result.push: ($chr.uniprop($key) ?? "<:$key>" !! "<:!$key>");
            }

        }
    }
    @result;

}
sub prefs {
    my %prefs = nqp::hash(
          'Other_Grapheme_Extend','B','Titlecase_Mapping','tc','Dash','B',
          'Emoji_Modifier_Base','B','Emoji_Modifier','B','Pattern_Syntax','B',
          'IDS_Trinary_Operator','B','ID_Continue','B','Diacritic','B','Cased','B',
          'Hangul_Syllable_Type','S','Quotation_Mark','B','Radical','B',
          'NFD_Quick_Check','S','Joining_Type','S','Case_Folding','S','Script','S',
          'Soft_Dotted','B','Changes_When_Casemapped','B','Simple_Case_Folding','S',
          'ISO_Comment','S','Lowercase','B','Join_Control','B','Bidi_Class','S',
          'Joining_Group','S','Decomposition_Mapping','S','Lowercase_Mapping','lc',
          'NFKC_Casefold','S','Simple_Lowercase_Mapping','S',
          'Indic_Syllabic_Category','S','Expands_On_NFC','B','Expands_On_NFD','B',
          'Uppercase','B','White_Space','B','Sentence_Terminal','B',
          'NFKD_Quick_Check','S','Changes_When_Titlecased','B','Math','B',
          'Uppercase_Mapping','uc','NFKC_Quick_Check','S','Sentence_Break','S',
          'Simple_Titlecase_Mapping','S','Alphabetic','B','Composition_Exclusion','B',
          'Noncharacter_Code_Point','B','Other_Alphabetic','B','XID_Continue','B',
          'Age','S','Other_ID_Start','B','Unified_Ideograph','B','FC_NFKC_Closure','S',
          'Case_Ignorable','B','Hyphen','B','Numeric_Value','nv',
          'Changes_When_NFKC_Casefolded','B','Expands_On_NFKD','B',
          'Indic_Positional_Category','S','Decomposition_Type','S','Bidi_Mirrored','B',
          'Changes_When_Uppercased','B','ID_Start','B','Grapheme_Extend','B',
          'XID_Start','B','Expands_On_NFKC','B','Other_Uppercase','B','Other_Math','B',
          'Grapheme_Link','B','Bidi_Control','B','Default_Ignorable_Code_Point','B',
          'Changes_When_Casefolded','B','Word_Break','S','NFC_Quick_Check','S',
          'Other_Default_Ignorable_Code_Point','B','Logical_Order_Exception','B',
          'Prepended_Concatenation_Mark','B','Other_Lowercase','B',
          'Other_ID_Continue','B','Variation_Selector','B','Extender','B',
          'Full_Composition_Exclusion','B','IDS_Binary_Operator','B','Numeric_Type','S',
          'kCompatibilityVariant','S','Simple_Uppercase_Mapping','S',
          'Terminal_Punctuation','B','Line_Break','S','East_Asian_Width','S',
          'ASCII_Hex_Digit','B','Pattern_White_Space','B','Hex_Digit','B',
          'Bidi_Paired_Bracket_Type','S','General_Category','S',
          'Grapheme_Cluster_Break','S','Grapheme_Base','B','Name','na','Ideographic','B',
          'Block','S','Emoji_Presentation','B','Emoji','B','Deprecated','B',
          'Changes_When_Lowercased','B','Bidi_Mirroring_Glyph','bmg',
          'Canonical_Combining_Class','S',
    );
}
```

Comment: I'd like to get a list of all the properties it satisfies without knowing the name of any of them in advance.

Comment: @briandfoy I have updated my answer with fully working code which will tell you what unicode regex will match. If you are interested the code which generates that hash which stores what type of property (boolean, string or integer) a property name is associated with it is https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/tools/build/makeUNIPROP.pl6 Let me know if I can be of any further help.

Comment: @briandfoy looks like I found a possible deficiency in our specification due to this question. Will need to investigate more, but seems I had assumed that <:!Property_Name> would match if the property value were an empty string (certain properties have an empty string as its null value), but it does not seem to always hold. Added a MoarVM issue for this, though I think it's likely it could be happening in NQP. Either case roast does not specify that this is guaranteed. https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/issues/818

Comment: I expected this to be a simple lookup with pre-computed values somewhere. I figure that code is below what the match operator is doing.

Comment: lookup of unicode properties is done on an in-memory datastructure that's generated from a few scripts in MoarVM's tools folder; the one @SamanthaM. linked to is responsible mainly for "what properties are there, what are their types, what extra names do they have". You can see the actual data in the unicode_db.c file, but watch out, it's about 7 megs in size: https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/blob/master/src/strings/unicode_db.c

Answer (score 1):

OK, so here's another take on answering this question, but the solution is not perfect. Bring the downvotes!

If you join [#perl6 channel on freenode](https://perl6.org/community/irc), there's a bot called [`unicodable6`](https://github.com/perl6/whateverable/wiki/Unicodable) which has functionality that you may find useful. You can ask it to do this (e.g. for character `A` and `π` simultaneously):

> <AlexDaniel> propdump: Aπ
>   <unicodable6> AlexDaniel, https://gist.github.com/b48e6062f3b0d5721a5988f067259727

Not only it shows the value of each property, but if you give it more than one character it will also highlight the differences!

Yes, it seems like you're looking for a way to do that within perl 6, and this answer is not it. But in the meantime it's very useful. Internally [Unicodable](https://github.com/perl6/whateverable/wiki/Unicodable) just iterates through [this list](https://github.com/perl6/whateverable/blob/master/lib/Whateverable/Uniprops.pm6) of properties. *So basically this is identical to the other answer in this thread.*

I think someone can make a module out of this (hint-hint), and then the answer to your question will be “just use module Unicode::Propdump”.