# How do I remove particular sets of characters and not others?

Tags: regex, raku

As a consequence of botched character decoding, I have a set of titles that look like this, with special characters followed by other characters like `ñ` that were not in the original:

```
P├ñiv├ñn J├ñlkeen
Tuuli k├ñ├ñnty├ñ voi
P├ñiv├ñn J├ñlkeen
Tuuli k├ñ├ñnty├ñ voi
∩╜óEurotrash∩╜ú
Le D├⌐sert N'Est Plus En Afrique
```

I know that I can use something along the lines of `s:g / ... / ... /`, but I am unsure of how to match just the special characters (`├`, `╜`) as opposed to capturing apostrophes, spaces, and so on.

When using `\W` to try and capture "not a character used in a 'word'", I run into the issue of it matching apostrophes, spaces, and so on.

Thus, my question is, what am I missing that would be useful when trying to essentially delete these characters from the words?

Comment: "everything as I stated above"   where?   There is no code golf, there is no expected versus seen outcome.  Your question is almost "I try to do something, it doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?".  Please improve the question!

Comment: I think these titles are UTF-8 strings interpreted as a different encoding – CP437 to be specific. I think you’d prefer to convert these to the correct encoding instead. Unfortunately, Raku itself doesn’t have an encoder for CP437, but you can do this using the command `iconv -f UTF-8 -t CP437`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR** Two solutions plus some further discussion.

## Simplest solution that works for your examples

```
<:So>
```

For example:

```
say
  S:g /<:So>//
given
  'P├ñiv├ñn J├ñlkeen' 

# Pñivñn Jñlkeen
```

## An explanation of the above solution

First, an explanation that looks short but will take you deep fast:

- Learn about [Unicode character properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property). Here's [the official Unicode Character Database doc](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/).
- Study Raku materials (eg [the latest Raku documentation on Unicode properties](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Unicode_properties)) and discussions (eg searches of SO: ["unicode property"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Braku%5D+%22unicode+property%22), ["unicode properties"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Braku%5D+%22unicode+properties%22)) about use of Unicode properties in Raku.
- Learn how the reference Raku compiler (Rakudo) actually uses them. (It gets complicated; see SO [What are all the Unicode properties a Raku character will match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245522/what-are-all-the-unicode-properties-a-perl-6-character-will-match/49287975#49287975).)

Now a slightly longer explanation that may make understanding this stuff easier than the approach outlined above:

- In Raku regexes, `<...>` is a general assertion that `...` is true. There are *many* variations on what `...` can be.¹
- One variation is that the current character is matched against a character class, or some combination of classes, specified by the `<...>`. There are *many* variations on what this Raku character class expression `...` can be.²
- One variation of a character class expression is an explicit Unicode character property value; it will match characters with that Unicode character property value. There are *many* variations on what a Unicode character property and its values can be; `<:So>` is an example and works for your scenario.³

Here's the process I went through to select that character class for your scenario:

1. I used a `util.unicode.org` hosted utility to see [properties of the `├` character](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=%E2%94%9C&B1=Show).⁴
2. I focused on the the `General_Category` property listed near the top of the left hand column of the table. This is a common property to specify in a Raku regex. You generally won't specify it by writing `<:General_Category...>`, with the `...` being the category, but instead by just writing `<:category>` where `category` is the category.
3. I noted the `General_Category` value (the next column): `Other_Symbol`. If you read the Unicode or Raku doc related to the `General_Category` property, you'll see that `So` is a short alias of `Other_Symbol`.
4. To specify a Unicode property in Raku, write it using Raku's colon pair literal syntax. The key can be any of many Unicode properties.⁵ So to match a character that has the `So` property, write `<:So>` in a regex.
5. To remove a character that has that class from a string, one option is to use the `s///` construct:

   ```
   say
     S:g /<:So>//
   given
     'P├ñiv├ñn J├ñlkeen' 

   # Pñivñn Jñlkeen
   ```

## Another way to get the same result

You might want to do "arithmetic" with character classes / characters, adding some, and subtracting others:

```
say
  S:g / <+ [\W] - [\s] - ['] > //
given
  'P├ñiv├ñn J├ñlkeen'

# Pñivñn Jñlkeen
```

Read `<+ [\W] - [\s] - ['] >` as "Not a word character, but also not a space character and not a `'` either".

See [Enumerated character classes and ranges](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Enumerated_character_classes_and_ranges) in the Character Class section of Raku's doc for further details of using enumerated classes (using `< [...] >`) and adding/subtracting classes (using `+` and `-`) and/or [an earlier SO I answer I wrote in response to a question pretty similar to yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57538843/perl6-regex-match-all-punctuations-except-and/57538993#57538993).

For some use cases this approach may simplify getting precisely the result you want and/or expressing it so it'll be easier for others, or a future you, to maintain. But it all depends on things I'll discuss in the next section.

## Further discussion of your question: "and so on"

> I am unsure of how to capture just the special characters as opposed to capturing apostrophes, spaces, **and so on**.

Let's say you use something like one or other or the two solutions I've shown. How do you know they really are what you want? The answer is you need to explore Unicode. Character classes like `\w`/`\W`, `\s`/`\S` etc are just convenient shortcuts for Unicode properties, so you still end up needing to explore Unicode if you want to be sure what's going on. Given that it all ultimately boils down to Unicode properties, let's discuss the `<:So>` solution.

As we saw above, the `General_Category` property of `├` (as shown via the utility linked above) is a link/value [`Other_Symbol`](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5B:General_Category=Other_Symbol:%5D).

If you click that latter link, you'll see a page corresponding to the Unicode `Other_Symbol` character class. It's a big jumbled mass of black-and-white symbols and colorful emojis and then an orderly list of other symbols. There are over 6,000 characters!

Does this character class contain characters that could be categorized as "spaces"? I'm near certain it doesn't, but it'll be up to you to figure that out, not me. What about "apostrophes"? I'm slightly less sure about that than "spaces", though I again think it won't include characters that could be called or categorized as "apostrophes". Does the `Other_Symbol` character class contain "and so on"?!? Maybe toss a coin?  Maybe do an in page browser search for particular characters on the `Other_Symbol` page?

---

When I'm not using the tools hosted on `util.unicode.org` or similar, one approach I've occasionally used to explore Unicode character classes is variations on this Raku code:

```
say (^0x10FFFF)».chr.grep(/ <:So> /)
```

The `(^0x10FFFF)` is a way to specify the integer `Range` that corresponds to all of the 1,114,112 legal Unicode Code Points. The `».chr` iterates the range, producing a list of integers from `0` onward, applying `.chr` to each, which produces the Unicode character corresponding to a given integer. The `.grep(/ <:So> /)` then keeps only the characters whose `General_Category` is `Other_Symbol`.

That said, that'll be really slow. You'll want to find other ways to explore Unicode.

Other options include the `util.unicode.org` tools and the Raku community's [`Unicodable`](https://github.com/Raku/whateverable/wiki/Unicodable) which you can run by [visiting the `#raku` IRC channel](https://kiwiirc.com/nextclient/irc.libera.chat/#raku) and entering `u: ...`.

## Discussion of "`$_ ~~ s:g / \├ / /;`"

> when I attempt to directly escape the character in my regex via `$_ ~~ s:g/ \├ / /;`, the result stays the same

I've not been able to reproduce that.

I think you've just gotten confused.

If you are still convinced you are right, please produce an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

## Footnotes

¹ A big chunk of Raku's power is in its powered up regexes. And a big chunk of *that* is expressed via the general form `<...>`.

² Character class syntaxes include older style ones carried forward from older regex formats, eg `\s` to match whitespace. But they're all just shortcuts for Unicode properties or characters rather than ASCII ones, and there are now a LOT more variations.

³ If you only skim the doc you might think that Raku regexes can only match against Unicode's `General_Category` property. But if you look at the code examples you'll see there's `<:Script<Latin>>` and `<:Block('Basic Latin')>` too. (But what are they?) And then when you see the vast array of properties displayed by the `util.unicode.org` property browser you realize there's *vastly* more that could be matched. Rakudo matches many of these but not all. For gory details, see [What are all the Unicode properties a character will match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245522/what-are-all-the-unicode-properties-a-perl-6-character-will-match/49287975#49287975).

⁴ Perhaps adding links to some of these utilities from the Raku doc would be a good thing. And/or creating/hosting variants of them using Raku.

⁵ I suspect Raku defines some additional things that are of the form `<:foo>` beyond Unicode properties. For example, I know `:space` works (it matches an ASCII space) but suspect it's not a Unicode property. Otoh that sounds downright wrong to me and against what I would expect of Raku design. If I find out for sure one way or the other I'll update this footnote.

Comment: My impression is that there are actually digraphs, with the ñ not being part of the original. I'd probably go for something a bit more complex... Instead of removing characters, some substitution might be needed.

Comment: @jjmerelo Ahhhh. ‍♂️ So maybe .@Homerian would best go in the other direction and figure out / fix whatever bogus encoding/decoding problem(s) there were in the first place?

Comment: I think @raiph's answer is very informative (although jjmerelo is probably more apt) and would like to see the Question reinstated by mods after some appropriate edits...

Comment: @p6steve. I just saw bb94's comment about CP437. But they're blocked from answering. Hmm. A new plan is hatched...

Comment: excellent to see this Q&A reinstated! - seems that your awesome answer is licensed by cc-sa ... so not that bad